# Training accuracy of CNN in Tensorflow not improving over 30 percent and cost remains almost same

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using a data set that consists of a list of 9(1 D data) real numbers(which represent function values at regularly spaced points). I then calculate the derivative of the function at the middle point using different difference function namely forward difference and backward difference etc. The labels( 12 in number) of my problem are the most favourable number of points to be chosen so that the calculated derivative is closest to the actual derivative.

I am using 2 convolutional layers for 1x9 list of real integers with stride =1 and window size = 2 for each and feature maps being 2 and 4. Then I have 2 fully connected layer with 500 and then 12 neurons.

My problem is that my accuracy is not going over 30 percent and cost remains around 2.5. Is there something I am doing wrong???

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.utils import np_utils

def calculation_of_labels(func,derf):
    #label=1

    f2f= (func[5]-func[4])/(0.125)
    #t=abs(f2f-derf)
    #actualDer= f2f
    f2b= (func[4]-func[3])/(0.125)
    f3=(func[5]-func[3])/(0.125*2)
    f4b=(2*func[5]+3*func[4]-6*func[3]+func[2])/(6*0.125)
    f4f= (-1*func[6]+6*func[5]-3*func[4]-2*func[3])/(6*0.125)
    f5=(-1*func[6]+8*func[5]-8*func[3]+func[2])/(0.125*12)
    f6b=(-3*func[6]+30*func[5]+20*func[4]-60*func[3]+15*func[2]-2*func[1])/(0.125*60)
    f6f=(2*func[7]-15*func[6]+func[5]-20*func[4]-30*func[3]+3*func[2])/(0.125*60)
    f7=(func[7]-9*func[6]+45*func[5]-45*func[3]+9*func[2]-1*func[1])/(0.125*60)
    f8f=(-3*func[8]+28*func[7]-126*func[6]+420*func[5]-105*func[4]-252*func[3]+42*func[2]-4*func[1])/(0.125*420)
    f8b=(4*func[7]-42*func[6]+252*func[5]+105*func[4]-420*func[3]+126*func[2]-28*func[1]+3*func[0])/(0.125*420)
    f9=(-3*func[8]+32*func[7]-168*func[6]+672*func[5]-672*func[3]+168*func[2]-32*func[1]+3*func[0])/(0.125*840)
    myList=[f2b,f2f,f3,f4b,f4f,f5,f6b,f6f,f7,f8b,f8f,f9]
    b=min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-derf))
    a=myList.index(b)
    return a

fun_mat=[]
lab=[]
#print(lab)
fun_der_mat=0

for number in range(0,50000):
    function=0
    fder=0
    #phi =random.uniform(0,1)
    Ak= random.uniform(1,5)
    xv=np.arange(0,1.1,0.125)
    for k in range(1,5):
        phi = random.uniform(0,1)
        function = function+ (Ak/k)*np.sin(2*np.pi*k*xv+ phi*2*np.pi)
        fder = fder+ (Ak)*2*np.pi*np.cos(2*np.pi*k*xv+ phi*2*np.pi)
        for j in range(0,9):
            function[j] = round(function[j],3)
            fder[j] = round(fder[j],3)        
    fun_mat.append(function)
    lab.append(calculation_of_labels(function, fder[4]))

logs_path = '/tmp/check/'

#inputdata,Label = shuffle(fun_mat,lab, random_state = 2)
#print(fun_mat)
#print(inputdata)
#raw_data = [inputdata, Label]
with tf.name_scope('input'):
        x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,9], name = "X_input")        
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,12], name = "Y_input")
x= tf.reshape(x,shape=[2000,1,9,1])
#MODEL BEING BUILT

def weight_variable(shape, nam):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1, name=nam)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape, na):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape, name = na)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,1,2,1],strides=[1,1,2,1], padding='SAME')


def next_batch(index_receive, dat, labels):
    '''
    Return a total of `num` random samples and labels. 
    '''
    """idx = np.arange(0 , len(dat))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]"""
    dat_shuffle = [dat[i] for i in index_receive]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[i] for i in index_receive]
    #for i in range(0, index_receive.size):
    return np.asarray(dat_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)

with tf.name_scope("Conv_Layer_1"):
        w_conv1 = weight_variable([1,2,1,2], "w_conv1")
        b_conv1= bias_variable([2],"b_conv1")
        tf.summary.histogram("weights",w_conv1)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases",b_conv1)

with tf.name_scope("Conv_Layer_2"):

        w_conv2= weight_variable([1,2,2,4],"w_conv2")
        b_conv2= bias_variable([4],"b_conv2")
        tf.summary.histogram("weights",w_conv2)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases",b_conv2)

with tf.name_scope("Fully_Conn_L_1"):
        w_fc1 = weight_variable([3*4,500], "w_fc1")
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([500], "b_fc1")
        tf.summary.histogram("weights",w_fc1)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases",b_fc1)

with tf.name_scope("Fully_Conn_L_2"):
        w_fc2 = weight_variable([500,12],"w_fc2")
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([12],"b_fc2")
        tf.summary.histogram("weights",w_fc2)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases",b_fc2)

#with tf.name_scope("Fully_Conn_L_3"):
        #w_fc3 = weight_variable([500,12],"w_fc3")
        #b_fc3= bias_variable([12], "b_fc3")
        #tf.summary.histogram("weights",w_fc3)
        #tf.summary.histogram("biases",b_fc3)


for i in range(0,50000):
        for j in range(0,9):
                fun_mat[i][j]= fun_mat[i][j]/5

X= fun_mat
y= lab
#(X,y)= (raw_data[0],raw_data[1])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=2)
X_train= np.array(X_train)
X_test= np.array(X_test)
#print(X_train)
X_train=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],9,1)
X_test= X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],9,1)
#print(X_train)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train,12)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,12)
#print(Y_train[1])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def model(data):
        with tf.name_scope("MODEL_LAYER_OUTPUTS"):
                h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(data, w_conv1)+ b_conv1)
                h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
                h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, w_conv2)+ b_conv2)
                h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
                h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2,[-1,3*4])
                h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat,w_fc1) + b_fc1)
                h_fc1_drop= tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1,keep_prob)
                #h_fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,w_fc2) + b_fc2)
                #h_fc2_drop= tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, keep_prob)
                tf.summary.histogram("CONV_Layer_1_act ", h_conv1)
                tf.summary.histogram("Pool_Layer_1_act ", h_pool1)
                tf.summary.histogram("CONV_Layer_2_act ", h_conv2)
                tf.summary.histogram("Pool_Layer_1_act ", h_pool2)
                tf.summary.histogram("F_C_Layer_1_act ", h_fc1_drop)
                #tf.summary.histogram("F_C_Layer_2_act ", h_fc2_drop)
                return tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,w_fc2) + b_fc2)
                #return tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,w_fc2) + b_fc2

y= model(x)
with tf.name_scope("COST"):
        #cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = y, labels=y_))+0.01*tf.nn.l2_loss(w_fc1) + 0.01*tf.nn.l2_loss(w_fc2))
        tf.summary.scalar("COST", cross_entropy)
with tf.name_scope("train"):
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("ACCURACY"):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
        tf.summary.scalar("ACCURACY", accuracy)
#sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
summ = tf.summary.merge_all()

saver = tf.train.Saver()
batch_size=2000
with tf.Session() as sess:
        #sess.run(init)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph= tf.get_default_graph())
        #writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
        for i in range(1000):
                avg_cost=0.
                #INDEX GENERATE
                index=np.arange(0,40000)
                np.random.shuffle(index)
                #extra = data_set_size%batch_size
                batch_count = 40000//batch_size + 1
                for j in range(batch_count):
                        start = j*batch_size
                        end_idx = start+ batch_size
                        if j == (batch_count - 1):
                                break
                        swiped_index= index[start:end_idx]
                        #print(swiped_index)
                        batch = next_batch(swiped_index, X_train, Y_train)
                        #print(batch[0])
                        batcht=np.reshape(batch[0],(batch_size,1,9,1))
                        _, summary = sess.run([optimizer, summ], feed_dict={x: batcht, y_: batch[1],keep_prob: 0.5})
                        #avg_cost += c / batch_count

                        #optimizer.run(feed_dict={x:batcht, y_: batch[1], keep_prob : 0.5})
                if i%50 == 0:
                        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batcht, y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                        writer.add_summary(summary, i * batch_count + i)
                        print("step %d, Training accuracy %g" %( i, train_accuracy))
                        #print("step %d, COST:  %g" %( i, avg_cost))
        saver.save(sess, "C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/intern 3july/model1_first")
        index_rec=np.arange(0,10000)
        np.random.shuffle(index_rec)
        swiped=index_rec[0:2000]
        batch1= next_batch(swiped,X_test,Y_test)
        batch1t=np.reshape(batch1[0],(batch_size,1,9,1))
        print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch1t, y_: batch1[1], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Comment: Can you post your code? What have you tried? If you provide a runnable example, it is much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @fbt I have included the code  here. Sorry but the code may be troublesome for you but please help. Its really necessary

Comment: @fbt can you help me please.